My DJI drone simulator can't switch into 'GUIDED' mode
I am running a simulator for my DJI drone so I can learn to use the drone before flying it in person. However, whenever I initialize the code the drone fails to enter GUIDED mode. This is my code:
import collections
import collections.abc
collections.MutableMapping = collections.abc.MutableMapping #this is a technical issue. might actually affect a future issue
#there was some sort of update that switched around the files, and this switches it back

from dronekit import connect, VehicleMode, LocationGlobalRelative
import dronekit_sitl

import time
import math
import threading
from pymavlink import mavutil
from pynput import keyboard
import dronekit_sitl

sitl = dronekit_sitl.start_default(lat=0, lon=0)
connection_string = sitl.connection_string()


class Location:
    def __init__(self, lat, lon, alt):
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.alt = alt
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Location(%s, %s, %s)" % (self.lat, self.lon, self.alt)


class DroneController:
    def __init__(self, connection_string=""):
        print(f"Attempting to connect to {connection_string}")
        self.vehicle = connect(connection_string, wait_ready=True, timeout=60)
        print("Successfully connected to the vehicle")

    def get_location(self):
        return Location(self.vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lat, 
                        self.vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lon, 
                        self.vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.alt)

    def arm_and_takeoff(self, target_altitude):
        print("Basic pre-arm checks")
        while not self.vehicle.is_armable:
            print(" Waiting for vehicle to initialise...")
            time.sleep(1)

        if not self.set_guided_mode():
            print("not guieded mode")
            return False

        print("Arming motors")
        self.vehicle.armed = True

        arming_timeout = 60
        start_time = time.time()
        while not self.vehicle.armed:
            if time.time() - start_time > arming_timeout:
                print("Failed to arm within timeout period")
                return False
            print(" Waiting for arming...")
            time.sleep(1)

        print("Taking off!")
        self.vehicle.simple_takeoff(target_altitude)

        takeoff_timeout = 30
        start_time = time.time()

        while True:
            current_altitude = self.vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.alt
            print(f" Altitude: {current_altitude}")
            if current_altitude >= target_altitude * 0.95:
                print("Reached target altitude")
                return True
            elif time.time() - start_time > takeoff_timeout:
                print("Takeoff failed, timeout reached")
                return False
            time.sleep(1)

    def pre_arm_check(self):
        print("waiting for vehicle to initialise")
        while not self.vehicle.is_armable:
            print("waiting for vehicle to initialise...")
            time.sleep(1)
        print("vehicle is ready to arm")

    def set_guided_mode(self):
        print("Attempting to set GUIDED mode")
        
        # Try to set mode using standard method
        self.vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("GUIDED")
        self.vehicle.flush()
        
        start_time = time.time()
        timeout = 10
        while self.vehicle.mode.name != 'GUIDED':
            if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
                print("Failed to set GUIDED mode within timeout period")
                print(f"Mode: {self.vehicle.mode.name}")
                return False
            time.sleep(1)
        print("GUIDED mode set successfully")
        return True
        
  

    def fly_to_point(self, location: Location):
        print("Flying to point")
        point_end = LocationGlobalRelative(location.lat, location.lon, location.alt)
        self.vehicle.simple_goto(point_end)

        # Wait until the drone reaches the correct spot
        while True:
            distance = self.distance_to(location)
            print(f"Distance to target: {distance:.2f} meters")
            if distance <= 1:
                print("Reached target point")
                break
            time.sleep(1)

    def land(self):
        print("Landing...")
        self.vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("RTL") #might be "LAND"

    def close(self):
        self.vehicle.close()

    def get_distance(self, location1: Location, location2: Location):
    #use the haversine formula to calculate the distance between two points on a 3d sphere
        earth_radius = 6371000 #meters
        lat1 = math.radians(location1.lat)
        lon1 = math.radians(location1.lon)
        lat2 = math.radians(location2.lat)
        lon2 = math.radians(location2.lon)

        dlat = lat2 - lat1 # differences in latitude and longitude
        dlon = lon2 - lon1

        #haversine formula to calculate the distance between two points on a sphere
        a = (math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2))
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))

        distance = earth_radius * c

        alt_diff = abs(location2.alt - location1.alt)
        total_distance = math.sqrt(distance**2 + alt_diff**2)

        return total_distance

    def distance_to(self, location: Location):
        current_location = self.get_location()
        return self.get_distance(current_location, location)
    
    def print_position(self):
        location = self.vehicle.location.global_relative_frame
        print(f"Position: Lat: {location.lat}, Lon: {location.lon}, Alt: {location.alt}")

    def position_printer(self, stop):
        while not stop():
            self.print_position()
            time.sleep(1) #print the position every second

    def keyboard_control(self):
        print("starting keyboard control. use arrow keys to move the drone, press 'q' to quit")
        with keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()

    def set_velocity(self, x, y, z, yaw):
        msg = self.vehicle.message_factory.set_position_target_local_ned_encode(
            0,       # time_boot_ms (not used)
            0, 0,    # target system, target component
            mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED, # frame
            0b0000111111000111, # type_mask (only speeds enabled)
            0, 0, 0, # x, y, z positions (not used)
            x, y, z, # x, y, z velocity in m/s
            0, 0, 0, # x, y, z acceleration (not supported yet, ignored in GCS_Mavlink)
            0, math.radians(yaw))    # yaw, yaw_rate (not supported yet, ignored in GCS_Mavlink)
        self.vehicle.send_mavlink(msg)
        self.vehicle.flush()
    
    def move_forward(self):
        self.set_velocity(5, 0, 0, 0)
        print("moving forward")
    
    def move_backward(self):
        self.set_velocity(-5, 0, 0, 0)
        print("moving backward")

    def move_left(self):
        self.set_velocity(0, 5, 0, 0)
        print("moving left")

    def move_right(self):
        self.set_velocity(0, -5, 0, 0)
        print("moving right")

    def move_up(self):
        self.set_velocity(0, 0, -5, 0)
        print("moving up")

    def move_down(self):
        self.set_velocity(0, 0, 5, 0)
        print("moving down")

    def stop(self):
        self.set_velocity(0, 0, 0, 0)
        print("stopping")

    def on_press(self, key):
        try:
            if key == keyboard.Key.up:
                self.move_forward()
            elif key == keyboard.Key.down:
                self.move_backward()
            elif key == keyboard.Key.left:
                self.move_left()
            elif key == keyboard.Key.right:
                self.move_right()
            elif hasattr(key, 'char'):
                if key.char == 'w':
                    self.move_up()
                elif key.char == 's':
                    self.move_down()
                elif key.char == 'q':
                    print("Quitting keyboard control")
                    return False
        except AttributeError:
            print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))
    
    def on_release(self, key):
        self.set_velocity(0, 0, 0, 0)
        print("stopping")
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    

    print("Connecting to vehicle on: %s" % connection_string)
    drone = DroneController(connection_string)

    stop_threads = False
    printer_thread = threading.Thread(target=drone.position_printer, args=(lambda: stop_threads,))
    
    try:
        print("Performing pre-arm check")
        drone.pre_arm_check()
        print("Pre-arm check completed. Attempting takeoff")
        print(f"Is Armable: {drone.vehicle.is_armable}")
        print(f"System Status: {drone.vehicle.system_status.state}")
        print(f"Mode: {drone.vehicle.mode.name}")

        takeoff_success = drone.arm_and_takeoff(10)
        if takeoff_success:
            print("Takeoff successful")
            time.sleep(2)
            
            print("Starting keyboard control")
            printer_thread.start()
            drone.keyboard_control()
        else:
            print("Takeoff failed. Checking vehicle state:")
            print(f"Is Armed: {drone.vehicle.armed}")
            print(f"System Status: {drone.vehicle.system_status.state}")
            print(f"Mode: {drone.vehicle.mode.name}")
            print("Aborting mission")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

    finally:
        print("Landing and closing connection")
        stop_threads = True
        printer_thread.join()
        drone.land()
        drone.close()
        sitl.stop()

and this is the error I keep getting:
Starting copter simulator (SITL)
SITL already Downloaded and Extracted.
Ready to boot.
Connecting to vehicle on: tcp:127.0.0.1:5760
Attempting to connect to tcp:127.0.0.1:5760
CRITICAL:autopilot:APM:Copter V3.3 (d6053245)
CRITICAL:autopilot:Frame: QUAD
CRITICAL:autopilot:Calibrating barometer
CRITICAL:autopilot:Initialising APM...
CRITICAL:autopilot:barometer calibration complete
CRITICAL:autopilot:GROUND START
Successfully connected to the vehicle
Performing pre-arm check
waiting for vehicle to initialise
waiting for vehicle to initialise...
waiting for vehicle to initialise...
waiting for vehicle to initialise...
waiting for vehicle to initialise...
waiting for vehicle to initialise...
vehicle is ready to arm
Pre-arm check completed. Attempting takeoff
Is Armable: True
System Status: STANDBY
Mode: STABILIZE
Basic pre-arm checks
Attempting to set GUIDED mode
Failed to set GUIDED mode within timeout period
Mode: STABILIZE
not guieded mode
Takeoff failed. Checking vehicle state:
Is Armed: False
System Status: STANDBY
Mode: STABILIZE
Aborting mission
Landing and closing connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/koviressler/Desktop/AeroCleanTech/Drone_Control/drone_controller.py", line 274, in <module>
    printer_thread.join()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1107, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join thread before it is started")
RuntimeError: cannot join thread before it is started

Don't worry about the thread error. I am simply using threading to print out the drone's position every second and the error only occurs because I only start the thread if the drone takes of correctly, which it isn't.
Please help
I tried debugging by adding tons of print statements, but it always led back to the GUIDED mode issue. It used to work, but one day I must have added something that broke it and it hasn't worked since. It could be a compatability issue.
